# How do I set 2 different properties to a single block of code

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 different java classes one for text view and another for checked text, I want to apply these properties on them, is the following block of code allowed for the same id? It shows me an error about improper structure. How do I apply these 2 properties to the same block of code (eg: com. abc1 and com.abc2 ).

```
<com.abc.views.CheckedTextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/selectable_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkMark="@drawable/toggle_selector" 
    android:padding= "10dp"/>

<com.abc.utils.FontTextView
    android:id="@+id/selectable_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#707070"
    foo:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two elements with the same ID.

If you try to reference the View with the ID `selectable_text`, how should Android decide whether you want the `CheckedTextView` or the `FontTextView`? It can't, and thus won't allow you to have two Views with the same ID in the same layout.

On a related note, you aren't "applying properties" called `CheckedTextView` and `FontTextView` to the same element; you are declaring that the element *is*  a `CheckedTextView` or a `FontTextView`.

Comment: I need a way to go about this, any clue how I can apply these two elements to the same block of code?

Comment: Without knowing more about why you need this functionality, it is hard to say. One possibility would be to add (and remove) these Views as needed in your code instead of your XML.